# C symbolic types, and disjoint union types?

Tags: c, haskell, data-structures, types, algebraic-data-types

Disclaimer: I am a Haskell programmer learning C.  In Haskell, we have data declarations like

```
data No = NO
```

where NO does not have any interpretation as a number.  If we had something equivalent in C, we could then do

```
union MaybeInt { enum No no; int just;};
```

Which could be used to do things like have an array which is initialized as No's.

```
int A[k];
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    A[i] = NO;
```

This would be useful in doing memoization because often one has some recurisve algorithm which looks things up in an array and based on the value looked up, either makes a recursive call or not.  For example: (for fibonacci numbers)

```
fibMem (int k){
    if (FIB[k] == NO)
      compute fibMem(k-1) + fib(k-2) and store the result in FIB[k]
    return FIB[k]
}
```

Now, of course, I could initialize FIB[i] to some absurd value like -100, and that works for this problem; however, given an arbitrary memoized routine, where I don't know the range of values, this kind of solution is not going to work.

The problem with using an enumeration type: The first thing I saw, that made me jump out of me seat saying "yes" was enum types.  I thought why not do something like `enum No {no};`  Well, there is a problem with initializing the array used for memoization with `no`s.  The problem is that `no` is defined to be `0` or some numeric constant of my choice if I like.  This is unsatisfactory because, if the value stored in the array is *supposed* to be zero (or that constant of my choice), then when I do the check `A[i] == no` it may supposed to be that way!  Thus, I will end up performing an un-needed recursion.

This brings us to question 1: How can I get a symbolic constant in C that is treated as a flag, that is incomparable to anything of a different type?

Now, the problem with unions.  A union stores all its fields in one single address.  Thus, for example, an update to maybeInt.just affects the value of maybeInt.no.  For example,

```
union MaybeInt maybeInt;
maybeInt.just=9;
printf("%d",maybeInt.just);
printf("%d",maybeInt.no);
```

prints 99.  What would be nice was if there was some sort of *disjoint* union type in C, so that if I used one of the values of the union, the other becomes unobtainable.

This brings us to the second and final question: how can one obtain a disjoint union type in C -- that is a type that has many possible variants, but only one at any given time.  I would like something to be able to do something like:

```
disjoint T {type1 name1 , .... };
```

and have the if T.name2 is set, then a reference to T.name1 throws an error.  Or even better any reference to T must go through some sort of case distinction.

If this cannot be done nicely, please explain why.

Comment: What's wrong with adding an abstraction?  Use a pointer or a second parallel array that indicates the initialization status of a given entry.

Comment: So let me see if I understand:  I have two arrays of exactly the same size.  The second array, at position i, has a value like True or False indicating whether the first array at position i has been initialized or not?

Comment: There is http://www.boost.org/libs/variant for sum types (a.k.a.  tagged unions, variant types, disjoint unions - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union#1970s_.26_1980s) with compile-time guarantees (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union#2000s), but it is for C++.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Discriminated unions are a very standard C idiom. You just have to keep the tag separate from the data:

```
struct Data
{
    enum DataType
    {
        NotSet,
        Integer,
        Infinity,
        Message
    } tag;
    union ValueType
    {
        int n;
        char const * msg;
    } data;
};
```

Now you just have to maintain tag discipline, i.e. only read from the value that's appropriate for the given tag, and update the tag after writing to a union member. For example:

```
void foo(struct Data const * x)
{
    switch (x->tag)
    {
    case NotSet:      // ...
    case Integer:     // use x->data.n
    case Infinity:    // ...
    case Message:     // use x->data.msg
    };

    x->data.msg = "Thank you!";
    x->tag = Message;
}
```

Comment: Yes, after Norum's comment I was thinking of something like struct Pair {int val, int setYes}.  However this solution is much sexier.  It seems though to require a little care on the programmer's part.  For example, one could do x -> data.msg = "Hello"; x -> tag=NotSet.  Is there any way to *force* the correct coordinations (at compile time say).

Comment: @JonathanGallagher: Yeah, of course, you could break everything if you wanted. You just shouldn't :-) You can make wrapper functions like `set_message(void * obj, char const * msg)` and hide the implementation.

Comment: @JonathanGallagher ANSI C does not support the level of abstraction you are looking for.  You can make a C file and header that will implement an ADT as a struct that includes a tag field and data field, as Kerrek showed, and you can even hinder people from mucking with the structure by limiting what is provided by the header file to an opaque pointer and some functions (a la smart constructors).  However, people are still going to be capable of performing pointer-based memory operations (among other things, due to C's weak typing).